# Toolbar buttons not working in Edit View Joomla Custom Component

Tags: custom-component, joomla3.3

I have created an edit view for my fields view. When I click any button (save, save & close, cancel) it does nothing. Here is my AddToolbar code:

protected function addToolbar()
    {

```
        JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('hidemainmenu', true);

        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $isNew = ($this->item->id == 0);
        if (isset($this->item->checked_out)) {
            $checkedOut = !($this->item->checked_out == 0 || $this->item->checked_out == $user->get('id'));
        } else {
            $checkedOut = false;
        }

        $canDo = ReportsHelper::getActions();

        JToolBarHelper::title(JText::_('COM_REPORTS_TITLE_NEWREPORT'), 'newreport.png');

        // If not checked out, can save the item.
        if (!$checkedOut && ($canDo->get('core.edit') || ($canDo->get('core.create')))) {

            JToolBarHelper::apply('field.apply', 'JTOOLBAR_APPLY');
            JToolBarHelper::save('field.save', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE');

        }
        if (!$checkedOut && ($canDo->get('core.create'))) {
            JToolBarHelper::custom('field.save2new', 'save-new.png', 'save-new_f2.png', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE_AND_NEW', false);
        }
        // If an existing item, can save to a copy.
        if (!$isNew && $canDo->get('core.create')) {
            JToolBarHelper::custom('field.save2copy', 'save-copy.png', 'save-copy_f2.png', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE_AS_COPY', false);
        }
        if (empty($this->item->id)) {
            JToolBarHelper::cancel('field.cancel', 'JTOOLBAR_CANCEL');
        } else {
            JToolBarHelper::cancel('field.cancel', 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE');
        }
}
```

Here is my code in the controller file: Field.php:

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.controllerform');

class ReportsControllerField extends JControllerForm
{

}
```

The toolbars do not seem to work. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I was able to add the toolbars, my only problem is the buttons do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by re-creating the display form in /views/fields/tmpl/edit.php.
Seems I mistyped the form name. After re-creating, the toolbars worked.